# Error none of following function Intent in cardview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-cardview

i want to use intent in my code

i use cardview then want to move to another view ,

i got error "none of the following function ..."

```
class ListResep(val listResep: ArrayList<Resep>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListResep.CardViewViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_resep, parent, false)
        return CardViewViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardViewViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val resep = listResep[position]
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load(resep.photo)
            .apply(RequestOptions().override(600, 400))
            .into(holder.imgPhoto)
        holder.tvName.text = resep.name
        holder.tvDetail.text = resep.detail

        holder.btnShare.setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "Share " + listResep[holder.adapterPosition].name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, DetailResep::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listResep.size
    }

    inner class CardViewViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var imgPhoto: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_item_photo)
        var tvName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name)
        var tvDetail: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_detail)
        var btnFavorite: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_set_favorite)
        var btnShare: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_set_share)
        var btnUnFavorite: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_unset_favorite)
    }
```

Comment: `val intent = Intent(context, DetailResep::class.java)`

Comment: un resolved reference : context

Comment: val intent = Intent(it.context, DetailResep::class.java)

Comment: show full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create private field Context inside the Adapter, pass it from constructor.

```js
class ListResep(private val context: Context, val listResep: ArrayList) : RecyclerView.Adapter()
```

Then in your onBindViewHolder must be:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { 
    ...
    Glide.with(context)
    ...

    val intent = Intent(context, DetailResep::class.java)
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```